# Replace string and encode it again

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java & just made a login, but I want to hide the password with stars. But if I use this snippet it will use the stars. How can I 'encode' it after replacing?

EDIT: The input is from a GuiTextBox, its a method of GuiScreen of Minecraft.

```
String input = passwd.getText();
char[] ca = new char[input.length()];
Arrays.fill(ca, '*');
String output = new String(ca);

passwd.setText(output);
```

Comment: `passwd` is a JTextField ? See [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html). If you dont keep the input somewhere, it will be lost.

Comment: ... or a JPasswordField? Please provide just a little more context/background and pertinent code so we can make heads or tails out of this.

Comment: passwd is an GuiTextBox, its a method of GuiScreen of Minecraft.

Comment: Please edit your question, ask it as if the people reading it have no idea about what you're code does, what you're trying to do -- that we can't read minds or see code not shown.

Comment: What class is GuiScreen by the way?

Comment: The class GuiScreen is a helper for every Gui, like the Multiplayer, Singleplayer or Ingame GUI of Minecraft.

Comment: You should provide the URL of the official documentation of these. I don't think there is a lot of regular Minecraft dev on SO.

Comment: Well, you don't have to be a Minecraft Dev, to understand, what an regular Textbox which just allows you to type something in it, is. I already got help and made it, but thanks.

Comment: Well you should know that a Dev use documentation to understand how a class works and how to use it correctly, there is no such thing as _regular Textbox_. It could provide what you need but I guess you check. The solution I gave will only works once but if that helps then ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to recreate something already existing.

Java provide the [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) that will do exactly what you want directly.

This is used easily like a `JTextField` but hidding the password on keystroke. And you have this solution to get the value (can't remember if getText() return the value too)

```
char[] input = passwordField.getPassword();
```

See this [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) for more information

---

EDIT

Since this is not a Swing component and I don't know it, I will give you an ugly solution ;)

You need to keep the `input` variable in memory. So instead of declaring `input` in the methods where you replace the value, declare it outside the methods (to be an instance variable)

Comment: I'm using the GuiTextBox, its a method of GuiScreen of Minecraft.

Comment: @zByte I've edited the answer since you have added this information a bit late.